# Несколько одинаковых View в LazyVGrid

Tags: swiftui

Есть задача, реализовать вьюшку с несколькими элементами внутри в виде плитки разделённых на группы. Для этого использовал LazyVGrid и Section. Рисует отлично, но во в группах могут попадаться повторяющиеся элементы. Из-за этого оно крешится с ошибкой:

```
Fatal error: each layout item may only occur once: file SwiftUI, line 0
2021-04-26 11:35:24.956495+0300 Homfy[18490:290813] Fatal error: each layout item may only occur once: file SwiftUI, line 0
```

Мой пример кода:

```
LazyVGrid(columns: rows, alignment: .leading) {
                ForEach (facility.floors) { floor in
                    Section(
                        header: Text(floor.name)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                    ) {
                        ForEach(floor.neighbors, id: \.self.id) { item in
                            NeigborItemView(neighbor: item)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Не могу придумать способа как обойти эту проблему без особых костылей, т.к. мы можем использовать VStack и HStack, но это решение не очень.

P.S. Изначально помогало добавить вьюшке `.id(UUID())`, но пока не проскролишь список до определённого момента, при расширении списка и это уже не помогает.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1225244

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вот такое не совсем красивое, но всё же решение, мы переносим LazyVGrid на один уровень ниже:

```
ForEach (facility.floors) { floor in
                LazyVGrid(columns: rows, alignment: .leading) {
                    Section(
                        header: Text(floor.name)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(.system(size: 14))
                    ) {
                        ForEach(floor.neighbors, id: \.self.id) { item in
                            NeigborItemView(neighbor: item)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Вроде работает нормально, но как по мне должно быть более изящное решение.